# Show Current Date onclick using jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the datepicker ui for jQuery. The calendar is loading fine. Now I want to fire an event showing the current date when I select a day. I am trying to use [this](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#event-onSelect) but not having any luck.

The function looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(AllPageLoads);

    function AllPageLoads()
    {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker();
        $('table.games tbody tr.top').each(function (index) { if (index % 2 == 0) { $(this).addClass("even"); } else { $(this).addClass("odd"); } });
        $('table.games tbody tr.bottom').each(function (index) { if (index % 2 == 0) { $(this).addClass("even"); } else { $(this).addClass("odd"); } });
    }

    function EpicFail(response, status, error)
    {
        alert(response + " / " + status + " / " + error);

}
$('.selector').datepicker("option", "onSelect", function (dateText, inst) {
  alert(dateText);
 });
```

html:

```
<h2>Current Data</h2>

<div id="datepicker">
</div>

<p>All Times Pacific/p>
<table id="games" class="games">
    <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Data1</th>
            <th>Data2</th>
            <th>Data3</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
  <tbody>

  <tr class="left">

        <td>6/9/2011</td>

        <td>901</td>

        <td>Team1</td>

        <td>Payer1</td>

        <td>info1</td>

        <td>OFF</td>

        <td>OFF</td>

    </tr>

    <tr class="right">

        <td>4:05 PM</td>

        <td>902</td>

        <td>Team2</td>

        <td>Palyer2</td>

        <td>info2</td>

        <td>OFF</td>

        <td>OFF</td>

    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The code is fine and works in my tests. Are you sure your are using jquery 1.8+?

Comment: I am using 1.4.4. Is the select functionality newer than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `$('.selector').` you are telling to jQuery: Look for the element who has `class="selector"` and perform this function.

But you don't have any element with this class name.

So, to solve the problem, simple add the code:

```
    function AllPageLoads()
    {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
           onSelect: function (dateText, inst) { alert(dateText); }
        });
        $('table.games tbody tr.top').each(function (index) { if (index % 2 == 0) { $(this).addClass("even"); } else { $(this).addClass("odd"); } });
        $('table.games tbody tr.bottom').each(function (index) { if (index % 2 == 0) { $(this).addClass("even"); } else { $(this).addClass("odd"); } });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because you initialized the `datepicker` at least once before what you are trying to do now. The binding (inside options as dictionary) you are using works only when initializing the first time.

Either move it to the 1st initialization statement or use:

```
$('.selector').datepicker("option", "onSelect", function (dateText, inst) {
                                                    alert(dateText);
                                                });
```

Comment: I updated my statement to match yours, but I still cant get the alert to fire.